# Bitwise XOR: Setting X bit

Tags: xor

I am a little confused about how to go about solving this one.

I read somewhere that

```
n ^ (1 << x)
```

Will solve it. Can I get to see a diagrammatic explanation of how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we work with 8 bit number First you start with `1`

which would look like this in binary

```
00000001
```

then use the `<<` operator to shift the bits of the operand by `x` bit

if `x = 4`

```
00001000 ( 16 in decimal, 0x10 in hexadecimal )
```

then use the `^` operator (xor) with the resulting operand

input `n=8` ( `00000100`)

result

```
     00000100
xor  00001000
  =  00001100
```

PS: `xor` would **flip** the bit **not set** it, if you want to set it whatever the initial state, use the `or` operator (`|`)

Comment: So the bitwise operator pads the left side of 1<<x with zeros and then XOR is performed?

Comment: I recommend you read the [wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts), of course it is the most common implementation of the bit shift operator.